# Confused about TIMESTAMPTZ internal conversion

Tags: postgresql, casting, timezone, timestamp

I've spent a lot of time reading about 'best practices' when it comes to handling timestamps in Postgres, and have got a lot of conflicting answers. When using the `TIMESTAMPTZ` data type, I had assumed that `NOW()` and `NOW() at time zone 'utc'` would result in the same data being inserted in the database. Numerous comments online have suggested that internally the timezone isn't actually stored, but instead converted to UTC.

Why is it then, that when I run the following I don't get duplicate results?

```
CREATE TABLE testtime(
  mytime TIMESTAMPTZ,
  descr VARCHAR
);

INSERT INTO testtime VALUES
  (NOW(), 'Now at NZST'),
  (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'utc', 'Now at UTC');
SELECT *
FROM testtime;
```

Result:

```
2016-02-17 02:08:30.845071  Now at NZST
2016-02-16 13:08:30.845071  Now at UTC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is the implicit **type cast** from `timestamp` to `timestamptz`.

- `now()` returns data type `timestamptz`.
- `now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` returns data type **`timestamp`**.
- `(now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::timestamptz` casts `timestamp` to `timestamptz`, **assuming your current time zone** in the process. This is where the difference is introduced.

And this is what happens when you `INSERT` a `timestamp` value into a `timestamptz` column. Postgres has to assume ***some*** time zone. You seem to have expected that UTC would be assumed. The more reasonable default is the current time zone setting, though. If you set UTC in your session, you get the behavior you expected.

Demo:

With my time zone 'Europe/Vienna', which is currently 1 hour ahead of UTC (during winter time):

```
SET timezone = 'Europe/Vienna';
SELECT now() AS now1
     , now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS now2
     , (now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::timestamptz AS now3;
```

```
              now1             |          now2              |           now3
-------------------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------
 2016-02-16 14:30:07.243082+01 | 2016-02-16 13:30:07.243082 | 2016-02-16 13:30:07.243082+01
```

The same with 'UTC' as time zone setting for the session:

```
SET timezone = 'UTC';
SELECT now() AS now1
     , now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS now2
     , (now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::timestamptz AS now3;
```

```
              now1             |          now2              |           now3
-------------------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------
 2016-02-16 13:30:58.739772+00 | 2016-02-16 13:30:58.739772 | 2016-02-16 13:30:58.739772+00
```

Note how the first two columns have **identical values** - even though the text representation in `now1` looks different, because that is adjusted to the time zone of the session, the value is the same.

The third column has a **different value**, because a different time zone was assumed for the type cast.

Basics here:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Comment: Absolutely fantastic explanation as usual. I really appreciate it. Thanks.